# VBA: How to get page to update after filling in the select box

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I'm trying to use the full matchup table on this page https://stats.nba.com/player/2544/head-to-head/?Season=2018-19&SeasonType=Regular%20Season
So far this is what I have:

```
Option Explicit
Sub BrowsetoSite()

Dim IE As Object

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "https://stats.nba.com/player/2544/head-to-head/?Season=2018-19&SeasonType=Regular%20Season"


Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop


IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("stats-table-pagination__select")(0).Value = "string:All"
On Error Resume Next
IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("stats-table-pagination__select")(0).Focus.FireEvent ("onchange")


End Sub
```

That fills in the page selection as "All", but the page does not upload like it does if you were to click that option on the website. How do I fix this?

Here is the HTML code for the selection:

```
<select class="stats-table-pagination__select ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" ng-model="vm.data.page" ng-options="p for p in vm.data.pages" aria-invalid="false">
<option label="All" value="string:All">All</option>
<option label="1" value="number:1" selected="selected">1</option>
<option label="2" value="number:2">2</option>
<option label="3" value="number:3">3</option>
<option label="4" value="number:4">4</option>
<option label="5" value="number:5">5</option>
<option label="6" value="number:6">6</option>
<option label="7" value="number:7">7</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I tried to test the issue and I am also only able to set dropdown value but it does not change the data in gridview. The site you are trying to automate is developed using Angular and it does not have onchange event. The data get updated using angular code. There is no JS event that we can try to trigger from the VBA code. I will try to search for a way to automate Angular dropdown. If I get any helpful information then I will try to provide you. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT It's not Angular, it's an html change event. But you can't trigger it with FireEvent. See my answer below please.

Comment: @Zwenn, I agree with you here. I tested your code and it fires the event. Your code is helpful for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code. *FireEvent* don't work for the most of the modern pages. You must use *dispatchEvent* and you can only dispatch an event, if you set it before and initialize it via *initEvent*. For that I use the private sub *TriggerEvent()* below.

Please read the comments for more information.

**Code in the head of the macro:**

```
Option Explicit

'With the following Windows api function we can do breaks less than 1 second
'It works with Excel 32 bit and Excel 64 bit
#If Win64 Then
  'For 64 bit systems
  Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr)
#Else
  'For 32 bit systems
  Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
#End If
```

**The main macro:**

```
Sub OpenAllPages()

Dim url As String
Dim browser As Object
Dim nodeDropdown As Object

  url = "https://stats.nba.com/player/2544/head-to-head/?Season=2018-19&SeasonType=Regular%20Season"

  'Initialize Internet Explorer, set visibility,
  'call URL and wait until page is fully loaded
  Set browser = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
  browser.Visible = True
  browser.navigate url
  Do Until browser.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
  'Wait a little bit to load the table into the page from server
  '(I have scheduled the break conservatively. You can try fewer seconds)
  Sleep (5000)

  'You must save the DOM objekt of the dropdown to an object
  'variable to be able to trigger the change event later
  Set nodeDropdown = browser.document.getElementsByClassName("stats-table-pagination__select")(0)
  'Set the value to the object variable
  nodeDropdown.Value = "string:All"
  'Trigger the change event
  Call TriggerEvent(browser.document, nodeDropdown, "change")
  'Wait a little bit to open the table with all results
  Sleep (500)

  'Do here something you want with the whole table of results
End Sub
```

**The macro to trigger an html event:**

```
Private Sub TriggerEvent(htmlDocument As Object, htmlElementWithEvent As Object, eventType As String)

  Dim theEvent As Object

  htmlElementWithEvent.Focus
  Set theEvent = htmlDocument.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
  theEvent.initEvent eventType, True, False
  htmlElementWithEvent.dispatchEvent theEvent
End Sub
```